# Limit the messages consumed per topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My Kafka consumer has to listen on multiple topics. Each topic defines a priority, say - high, low and medium.

The consumer service has to be configured in such a way that, it has
for eg. 30 executors for processing messages in ***high*** topic and 5 executors for processing each message in ***low*** and ***medium*** topic.

Is there a way to configure the consumer to stop consuming message from the corresponding topic if the executors are occupied and running the current tasks?

Comment: if you are using `ThreadPoolExecutor` the call method to get active threads if that is equal to your executors you set then don't consume and wait for executors to get free else start consuming from topic.

Comment: Thanks Rahul!! any reference on how to do it with spring-kafka with minimal code?

Comment: can you share what you have done so far

Comment: Maybe it's the case for Kafka Quotas: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#sts=Enforcing%20Client%20Quotas%C2%B6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be handing off work to a task executor; it will cause problems with committing offsets out of order.

You should use different listener containers for each topic, each with a different concurrency setting.

That way the container manages the concurrency.